# Next.js api route is not handling cross-domain post request

Tags: javascript, next.js

I need to handle a POST request in my NextJS app. This post request is coming from a different domain.

I added this `receptor.ts` file into my `/pages/api` directory:

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';

export default function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  if (req.method === 'POST') {
    console.log('POST')
    const message = req.body.message;
    console.log(`Message: ${message}`);
    res.status(200).json({ message: "Ok" });
  } else {
    res.status(405).json({ error: "Not allowed" });
  }

  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST');
}
```

and in the other app this is how I call it:

```
const url = `http://localhost:3000/api/receptor`;
            const data = { message: "Hello" };

            fetch(url, {
              method: "POST",
              headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
              body: JSON.stringify(data)
            })
              .then(response => response.json())
              .then(data => console.log(data))
              .catch(error => console.error(error));
```

The browser's console says:

> Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:3000/api/receptor' from origin 'http://localhost:3001' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

And the IDE's console says:

> error - Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

If I add `mode: "no-cors"` to the request, then I got the same errors.

Any hint on how to solve this?

**SOLUTION**

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';

export default function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');

  if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    res.status(200).end();
    return;
  }

  if (req.method === 'POST') {
    console.log('POST')
    const message = req.body.message;
    console.log(`Message: ${message}`);
    res.status(200).json({ message: "Ok" });
  } else {
    res.status(405).json({ error: "Not allowed" });
  }
}
```

The thing is I wasn't handling the prefly request. Here is the solution and I will vote for closing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your api route is not responding properly to `OPTIONS` request. You need to make sure it handles `OPTIONS` request method and returns corresponding `Access-Control-*` headers. You may also need to include `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type` header.

Comment: Yes, that is the solution indeed. Thanks. I will update my question and request to close it with the solution.